# Alternative to then() function

Tags: javascript, php, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on a project that requires a PayPal payment gateway. I found a simple tutorial online that works fine, with the exception that the PayPal Response is sent to the console log. Looking online for any instance were the then() function is used for other than logging to console came up empty. The present code:

```
return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
            console.log(details);
```

needs to be changed, to a function other than then() in order to send the JSON object to the PHP processing page. Being a backend developer, I'm not sure what function that will be. Can anyone make a suggestion please? The entire code is as follows:

The HTML & JS Script

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Paypal Payment</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main id="cart-main">
        <div class="site-title text-center">
            <h3 class="font-title">Shopping Cart</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="col-1">
                    <div class="flex item justify-content-between">
                        <div class="flex">
                            <div class="img text-center">
                                <img src="./assets/pro1.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="title">
                                <h3>Canon EOS 1500D</h3>
                                <span>Electronics</span>

                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i> </button>
                                    <input type="text" class="font-title" value="1">
                                    <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> </button>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#">Save for later</a> |
                                <a href="#">Delete From Cart</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="price">
                            <h4 class="text-red">$349</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="subtotal text-center">
                        <h3>Price Details</h3>

                        <ul>
                            <li class="flex justify-content-between">
                                <label for="price">Products ( 1 item ) : </label>
                                <span>$399</span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="flex justify-content-between">
                                <label for="price">Delivery Charges : </label>
                                <span>Free</span>
                            </li>
                            <hr>
                            <li class="flex justify-content-between">
                                <label for="price">Amout Payble : </label>
                                <span class="text-red font-title">$399</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="paypal-payment-button">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>


    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ASbdZ8CH5kN5y98rzOuKMLPYsHl4QHLYcDGJ6lgaRjxiRp97t53sPWr1yG5vyd9mlHbyqw3vGUZaJsok&disable-funding=credit,card"></script>
    <script>
    // Create a Global var - the HTML charge is dummy stuff
    window.charge = 0.27;
    
    paypal.Buttons({
    style : {
        color: 'blue',
        shape: 'pill'
    },
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units : [{
                amount: {
                    value: window.charge 
                }
            }]
        });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
            console.log(details);
            window.location.replace("https://localhost/PayPal_Simple/payPalResponse.php?q=good");
            window.alert('This was successful.');
        })
    },
    onCancel: function (data) {
        window.location.replace("https://localhost/PayPal_Simple/payPalResponse.php?q=bad");
        window.alert('Something went wrong!');
    }
}).render('#paypal-payment-button');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP

```
<?php

// Get the Response from PayPal
$status = $_GET['q'];

// Once there is an object that can be tested, that will be used instead of ?q=
if($status = "good") {
    echo "The payment was a success.<br />";
} elseif($status = "bad") {
    echo "The charge was cancelled.";
} else {
    echo "Something else went wrong.";
}

// Of course, this doesn't display anything
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST); 
echo '<pre>';

// Insert data into the database

// Redirect the client to another page

?>
```

Thanks so much in advance for your help!
Cheers,
Rick

Comment: To send stuff to your PHP backend you will want to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API  but you still use `then`, the code you put inside `then` can do more than just console log.

Comment: Wow! That was the fastest comment ever, Keith. Thank you, I'll start looking at fetch!

Answer (score 3):

Do ***not*** capture on the client side and then send data to a backend. Instead, change to a proper server-side integration--the backend should be communicating with PayPal itself and sending data to the client on request.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thank you Preston. I've been messing with Fetch() since last night. The PayPal tutorial and articles showed this being done on the client side, which seemed odd, others payment providers capture an authorization and send that data to the back end to make the actual charge. I'll check the docs you linked.

Comment: The simple client-side integration captures on the client-side, sure. But do not do this if your use case is to write to a server database afterward.

Answer (score 0):

As [This link reads](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/11/comparison-async-await-versus-then-catch/)  , try using

**onApprove**

''''

```
const onApprove= new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  {resolve((data,actions) => {actions.order.capture(data,actions)}});
});
```

''''

*buttonPushFunction*

''''

```
async function doYourButtonPush() {
  try {
    await onApprove;
    console.log("The Promise is resolved!", value);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("The Promise is rejected!", error);
  } finally {
    function (details) {
            console.log(details);
            window.location.replace("https://localhost/PayPal_Simple/payPalResponse.php?q=good");
            window.alert('This was successful.');
        }
  }
}
```

''''

Comment: Thank you StarshipladDev, I'll check this out as well. I appreciate all the help!